# How can I post a 2D JavaScript array to the server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an array, myData=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],....,[..,..,..]]
I want to post this to the server.

Usually, for a JS variable, I just put the variable into a textbox and then submit the form using JS. However, when I put the 2D array into a textbox, JS converts it to a string, such that it becomes a 1D array, which looks like:
[1,2,3,4,5,6....]

I want to be able to post the entire 2D array to the server and retrieve it on the next page using PHP. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON to turn the array into a string with javascript and then parse the string back into an array in php.

for example:

```
var myData = var data = [['hooray',1],['test','meow'],[0,3,2]];
var myData_string = JSON.stringify(myData);
```

This will turn your object/array into a string which you can then POST and parse with php like so:

```
$myData = json_decode($input);
```

**References:**

- [**JSON** (javascript)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
- [**json_decode()** (php)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)